# How do I publish a book at age 12?

Tags: publishing

I'm writing a book called *The Lost Mermaid*. It's about a girl named Hazel waking up with no memory, and it turns out she has a boyfriend, Leo, but likes her best friend Eli. To make matters worse, a witch that wants vengeance on all of her mother's kids, has her twin brother Nico captured, and now she has to save him along with her friends Eli, Sky, and Leo.

The people I have called don't want to work with me, because I'm a kid. **How can I get my book published despite being only 12?**

Comment: Hi Railene and welcome! Your question is a great one and has been asked frequently here before.  Please check these questions: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36089/how-to-get-published-at-a-young-age https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/is-it-okay-to-publish-a-book-at-a-young-age https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33234/how-to-get-my-book-taken-seriously-as-a-teenager/33239#33239 https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32304/how-old-do-you-have-to-be-to-self-publish By the way, one of my favorite authors, Gordon Korman, was first published at age 12.

Comment: By the way, I would suggest you consider some less common names for your characters, as at least three of those names (Hazel, Nico, Leo) are from Rick Riordan's ridiculously popular fantasy novels.